# File turns to folder

Tags: java, file, directory

So, I'm having a hard time with files. I've used files before, but this time they are being a pain.

```
public SaveFile(File newFile)
{
    this.file = newFile;

    boolean first = false;
    if(!file.exists()){
        file.mkdir();
        first = true;
    }

    if(file.isDirectory()){
        throw new IllegalStateException("Save file can not be a folder");
    }

    if(file.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("current")){
        first = false;
    }

    this.config = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(this.file);

    String name = file.getName();

    name =  name.substring(0, name.lastIndexOf("."));

    if(first){
        config.set("name", name);
        config.set("health", 20.0F);
        config.set("level", 0);
    }

    try {
        config.save(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I create one save file, it works no problem. I can view and edit the file, which is great. However, if I attempt to create a second SaveFile, it turns the NEW file into a folder and throws an IllegalStateException

This is how it looks:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    SaveFile robert = new SaveFile(new File(SaveFile.getSaveFolder(), "Robert.save"));
    SaveFile james = new SaveFile(new File(SaveFile.getSaveFolder(), "James.save");
}
```

The SaveFile *robert* is created, and looks like its supposed to.
The SaveFile *james* is created as a folder, and throws an IllegalStateException

Comment: what do you expect `file.mkdir();` will do?

Comment: I expect it will make the file, which it does. Using `file.mkdirs()` throws FileNotFoundException

Comment: Nope, [File#mkdir](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir%28%29) creates a directory. Please check the javadoc of methods before using them to know how to uses them.

Comment: The only difference in the javadoc is this line `including any necessary but nonexistent parent directories.`

So, on both it says, `Creates the directory named by this abstract pathname.` so, how am I to know? It's not helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you are trying to create a file in a parent directory and you want to check whether the parent directory exists and create it first if required.

You need to get the parent of the file you pass which is the directory you may want to create using [File#getParentFile()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParentFile%28%29). This method returns a File object of witch you have to call [File#mkdirs()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29).

You could proceed like this for example:

```
public void saveFile(File newFile)
{
    File file = newFile;

    if(! file.exists()){
        File dir = file.getParentFile();
        if(! dir.exists()) {
            if(dir.mkdirs()) {
                System.out.println("parent directory " 
                    + dir.getPath() + " created");
            }
            if(! dir.isDirectory()){
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to create directory "
                 + dir.getPath());
            }
        }
    } else {
        if(file.isDirectory()){
            throw new IllegalStateException("Save file can not be a folder");
        }
    }

    // ...

    System.out.println("Save file " + file.getPath() + " created");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're problem is here, as noted in my code comments:

```
boolean first = false;
if(!file.exists()){
    // the following line is turning the file into a directory if the file
    // doesn't already exist
    file.mkdir();
    first = true;
}

// now you are checking if the directory you just created is a directory
// (this will, of course, be true) and thus throw the exception
if(file.isDirectory()){
    throw new IllegalStateException("Save file can not be a folder");
}
```

So it looks like "Robert.save" exists, and thus works, but "James.save" doesn't so it get created as a directory.

Answer (score 0):

It has something to do with this line of code:

```
file.mkdir();
```

,which makes a directory out of the path of the `File` object you pass as parameter. So, if none of the files (`Robert.save` and `James.save`) exist before the execution, it will create two **directories** named `/your/path/Robert.save` and `/your/path/James.save`.

The fact that it only creates one directory may only be caused by the fact that `Robert.save` might already exist before you execute your code. So the `mkDir` method won't be called because the following condition isn't validated:

```
if(!file.exists())
```